# Using method from one class within method for other class

Tags: r

I am trying to use a method for one class (data.frame) within a method for another class (list), in this case a list of several data frames.

This does not work, and I strongly assume due to some scoping problems. In my case `foo.data.frame` doesn't find `funs` anymore. If tried a few things to re-define `funs` (see comments in code), to no avail.

So, my question would be, how could I make `funs` accessible to `foo.data.frame` within `foo.list`. Or, are there good reasons why this is bad programming style. (I am still considering myself a programming beginner). Cheers.

*update*

I could define `funs` in the global environment - and I am happy to do that. But is there a way to access the environment created by useMethod, kind of from within the method in the method?

```r
set.seed(42)
mydf <- cbind(a = rep(letters[1:3], 4), setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(c(rnorm(11), NA), n = 3)), letters[24:26]))
mydf_grouped <- split(mydf, mydf$a)

foo <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(
    mean = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
  UseMethod("foo", x)
}

foo.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  suppressWarnings(lapply(funs, mapply, x))
}
## works
foo(mydf)
#> $mean
#>          a          x          y          z 
#>         NA  0.6161670 -0.4570349  0.2275039

## works with a simple function
foo.list <- function(x, ...){ 
  lapply(x, nrow)
}
foo(mydf_grouped)
#> $a
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 4

## fails with the method for data.frames
foo.list <- function(x, ...){ ## adding funs argument does not help
  # funs <- funs ## does not work 
  # funs <- list(
  #   mean = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  # )         ## Defining funs within foo.list does not work either
  lapply(x, foo.data.frame ) ## adding funs here does also not help
}
foo(mydf_grouped)
#> Error in lapply(funs, mapply, x): object 'funs' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `foo.data.frame` *directly*, and that function defines no `funs`. You *need* to call it via the generic `foo`:

```
foo.list <- function(x) {
  lapply(x, foo)
}
```

This works, since `foo` in `lapply` will call the generic which correctly dispatches to the appropriate method (`foo.data.frame`) in the case of calling it with a list of data.frames, as in `foo(mydf_grouped)`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense and is in agreement with the documentation (in contrast to my (technically wrong) answer below)!

Comment: @dario Credit where it’s due, your comment below first alerted me to the fact that this should actually work. Which is crazy: due to a low-level library I’m working on, and working around bugs and changes in R’s behaviour, I’ve spent many hours reading S3 documentation and source code, and yet I was until now somehow unaware that definitions in the generic are visible in the methods.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit: This answer is not correct.

See the accepted answer above for an explanation.

---

If you move the foo assignement out of the method declaration into foo.data.frame it works:

```
set.seed(42)
mydf <- cbind(a = rep(letters[1:3], 4), setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(c(rnorm(11), NA), n = 3)), letters[24:26]))
mydf_grouped <- split(mydf, mydf$a)

foo <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("foo", x)
}

foo.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  funs <- list(
    mean = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
  suppressWarnings(lapply(funs, mapply, x))
}

foo.list <- function(x, ...){

  lapply(x, foo.data.frame )
}
foo(mydf_grouped)
```

Returns:

> ```
> $a
> $a$mean
> a          x          y          z
> NA  0.8631572 -0.2024425  0.1406371
>
>
> $b
> $b$mean
> a          x          y          z
> NA  0.2624452 -1.2436714  0.3381285
>
>
> $c
> $c$mean
> a         x         y         z
> NA 0.7584759 0.2523572 0.1958268
> ```
>
> Blockquote

Comment: thanks that’s already helpful. but then funs won’t be available for other methods for this generic any more. I mean I can of course always redefine it

Comment: a better option would be here I guess to define `funs` in the global environment instead

Comment: Yea, I was thinking the same but then seemed to remember that in [the (sparse) documentation for UseMethod](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/UseMethod) it said that assignements *before* useMethod call are kept around... so Tjebo was on the right track?!